# OSError Bad file descriptor when using Popen

Tags: python, subprocess

I write the following sample code as demonstrating my problem:

```
from subprocess import Popen

while 1:
    try:
        proc = Popen(['tail', '-3', '/var/log/syslog'])
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        break
```

When I type ctrl + c, I'll get the traceback:

```
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py" line 1317, in _execute_child
  os.close(errpipe_read)
OSError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor
```

I originally think the file descriptor is shared between by spawn process and the parent process, so after goolgling I try the following code:

```
proc = Popen(['tail', '-3', '/var/log/syslog'], preexec_fn=os.setpgrp)
```

But still have that traceback log. How can solve this? Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: Not reproducible on my Debian 8 system. What is your environment?

Comment: I use Ubuntu. This happens by chance. In my case this happens about once per 5 times.